# Pass substring of values inside Where clause conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to pass substring of parameter values inside where clause statement

Parameter Value is pmtr: CN

Query:

I want to filter CAN country from the below table using one column but my parameter value holds one 2 digits (CN) but I have to filter records for Canada country from database which holds 3 digits (CAN). I am trying to get the substring of 1st position of parameter value and then appends with hardcoded char 'A' then again take substring of second position of parameter value in below query.

```
Select a,b 
from tab 
where a='pmtr[1,1]':'A':'pmtr[2,1]'
```

Tried with substring function it didn't work giving no result. Is there any way to achieve in filter condition using sql?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What is your schema?

Comment: sql server is the DB  I am using and oltp is the schema

Comment: `SUBSTRING(...) + 'A' + SUBSTRING(...)`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter only Canada (CN):

```
Select a,b 
from tab 
where CASE WHEN pmtr = 'CN' and a= 'CAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END =1
```

Note: This has a hard coded condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try with using a variable:

```
declare @var =concat(pmtr[1,1],'A',pmtr[2,1])
Select a,b 
from tab 
where a=@var
```